# Vue component's prop set to instance data mutates the upstream value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am seeing some weird behaviour here that was unexpected, but it makes intuitive-sense to me in terms of pure JavaScript.

I have a form controller that accumulates a `this.thing` object that is sent to the server on the final submit. It's a multi-step form, so each step adds some data to `this.thing`.

So the controller has:

```
data() {
    return {
        thing: {},
    };
},
```

The DOM markup for this controller has a child like:

```
<a-child
    :initial-thing="thing"
></a-child>
```

The child uses that prop to display its initial state, so it receives the prop and sets it into its own local state as instance data:

```
initialThing: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
},

...

data() {
    return {
        thing: this.initialThing,
    };
},
```

Then this child has a checkbox that is like this:

```
<a-checkbox
    v-model="thing.field"
    :initial-value="initialThing.field"
></a-checkbox>
```

This all works fine, except I just noticed that when the checkbox changes, it's mutating the parent controllers `thing.field` value.

I'm making this question because I don't understand how Vue can do that, and the only thing that makes sense to me is that when the child does `thing: this.initialThing`, it's allowing the child to call the setter function on that field on `this.initialThing`.

It stops mutating the parent's state if I do this instead:

```
data() {
    return {
        thing: { ...this.initialThing },
    };
},
```

In my actual app, it's more complex because there are 2 intermediate components, so the grandchild is mutating the grandparent's state, and it stems from the pattern I am describing here.

Can anyone provide a kind of textbook answer for what is happening here? I'm hesitant to rely on this behaviour because the code driving it is not explicit. It makes some of my `$emit()` events redundant in favour of using this indirect/non-explicit way of sending data upstream.

Also to be clear, this has nothing to do with `v-model` because it also does it if I do `this.thing.field = 'new value';`. I believe it has everything to do with inheriting the getters/setters on `this.initialThing`. Is it safe to rely on this behaviour? If I rely on it, it will make my code more concise, but a naive individual may have a hard time understanding how data is making it into the grandparent component.

Comment: I suppose thing is passed by reference. Would not rely on it as it breaks self containment of components making it more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Check this SO question for a more in depth answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **shallow copy** so you can't prevent mutating grandchildren.

```
data() {
    return {
        thing: { ...this.initialThing },
    };
},
```

The **solution** is below:

```
data() {
    return {
        thing: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialThing)),
    };
},
```

```js
const initialThing = {
  age: 23,
  name: {
    first: "David",
    last: "Collins",
  }
}

const shallowCopy = { ...initialThing };

shallowCopy.age = 10;
shallowCopy.name.first = "Antonio"; // will mutate initialThing

console.log("init:", initialThing);
console.log("shallow:", shallowCopy);

const deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialThing));
deepCopy.age = 30;
shallowCopy.first = "Nicholas"; // will not mutate initialThing

console.log("------Deep Copy------");
console.log("init:", initialThing);
console.log("deep:", deepCopy);
```

**How it works:**

```
JSON.stringify(this.initialThing)
```

This converts JSON `Object` into `String` type. That means it will never mutate children anymore.
Then `JSON.parse` will convert `String` into `Object` type.

> But, using stringify and parse will be expensive in performance. :D

**UPDATED:**
If you are using lodash or it is okay to add external library, you can use [_.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

```
_.cloneDeep(value); // deep clone
_.clone(value); // shallow clone
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct if you can re-work it to show that shallow cloning with `Object.assign({}, obj)` or spread operator is viable, but the best way is to deep clone. I'm going to use lodash cloneDeep for this purpose. I likely wouldn't ever use JSON stringify&parse, but it is an option. This URL here is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/10916838#10916838 as is the one linked by BTL in a comment on the original question.

Comment: The interesting thing from the link I provided is the native deep cloning. This is something we should be tracking in questions related to mine. I will give you a bonus point in real life if you include `import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';` to ensure people aren't importing the entire Lodash library.